c# casting array of bytes to array of structures
I have this code in c# where I need copy array of bytes to array of structures in the fastest way.
I have this structure:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
unsafe public struct TsVarGroup
{
    public uint Addr;       
    public ushort Count;    
    public short CAddr;     
    public ushort CSW;      
    public fixed byte NamePrefix[9];

    public string GetNamePrefix()
    {
        fixed (byte* ptr = NamePrefix)
        {
            return new string((sbyte*)ptr, 0, 8, Encoding.ASCII);
        }
    }
}

asVarGroups = new TsVarGroup[sVarTable.Count];
byte[] dataVarGroups = Connection.GETMEM("R", (sVarTable.Addr - ADDRESS_OFFSET), asVarGroups.Length * TS_VARGROUP_SIZE);

Is there any easy way how to copy aray of bytes dataVarGroups to array of structures asVarGroups ?
I tried this:
Buffer.BlockCopy(dataVarGroups, 0, asVarGroups, 0, dataVarGroups.Length); 

but it is only for primitives elements.

Does this answer your question? In C#, is it possible to cast a byte array into another type without creating a new array?

You can use MemoryMarshal.Cast to coerce a span of one blittable kind to another; arrays can be treated as spans, and both bytes and your type seems blittable, so:
byte[] bytes = ...
TsVarGroup[] target = ...

MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, TsVarGroup>(bytes).CopyTo(target);

You can do this to coerce blittable types in any direction. The resultant spans will be sized correctly according to the respective sizes of the two types being punned - i.e. if you coerce a span of 100 bytes to int, it will have length 25.
This works similarly to coercing unmanaged pointers, but doesn't require pinning or unsafe code (although obviously: you still need to be careful).
Most commonly, this kind of coercion is used to avoid ever needing a second array, allowing you to work on one array kind as though it were another (via spans).

If you're using C# 12 or later, you can do this without using any unsafe code by using the new System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray attribute to define your fixed array of 9 bytes, like so:
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(9)]
public struct NineBytes
{
    byte _element0;

    public static NineBytes Create(IReadOnlyList<byte> bytes)
    {
        var result = new NineBytes();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            result[i] = bytes[i];

        return result;
    }
}

I've added a Create() helper method to that struct just for the demo program below; it's not a necessary part of the struct.
Once you have that, you can declare your struct like so:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct TsVarGroup
{
    public uint      Addr;
    public ushort    Count;
    public short     CAddr;
    public ushort    CSW;
    public NineBytes NamePrefix;

    public string GetNamePrefix()
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(NamePrefix);
    }
}

Then you can use MemoryMarshal.Cast<> to cast (without copying data) from an array of bytes to a Span<TsVarGroup> or ReadOnlySpan<TsVarGroup>:
Span<TsVarGroup> fromBytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, TsVarGroup>(asBytes);

Putting that all together in a simple Console test app (DotNetFiddle here):
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Net8Console;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create array of structs:

        TsVarGroup[] original = [
            new TsVarGroup
            {
                Addr       = 1,
                Count      = 2,
                CAddr      = 3,
                CSW        = 4,
                NamePrefix = createNineAsciiBytes('A')
            },
            new TsVarGroup
            {
                Addr       = 2,
                Count      = 3,
                CAddr      = 4,
                CSW        = 5,
                NamePrefix = createNineAsciiBytes('B')
            },
            new TsVarGroup
            {
                Addr       = 3,
                Count      = 4,
                CAddr      = 5,
                CSW        = 6,
                NamePrefix = createNineAsciiBytes('C')
            }
        ];

        byte[]           asBytes   = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(original.AsSpan()).ToArray();
        Span<TsVarGroup> fromBytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, TsVarGroup>(asBytes);

        // No copying of the 'asBytes' array occurs when creating 'fromBytes'.

        for (int i = 0; i < fromBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fromBytes[i].GetNamePrefix());
        }
    }

    static NineBytes createNineAsciiBytes(char firstChar)
    {
        return NineBytes.Create(nineAsciiChars((byte)firstChar).ToList());
    }

    static IEnumerable<byte> nineAsciiChars(byte firstChar)
    {
        for (byte ch = firstChar, lastChar = (byte)(ch + 9); ch != lastChar; ++ch)
            yield return ch;
    }
}

[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(9)]
public struct NineBytes
{
    byte _element0;

    public static NineBytes Create(IReadOnlyList<byte> bytes)
    {
        var result = new NineBytes();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            result[i] = bytes[i];

        return result;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct TsVarGroup
{
    public uint      Addr;
    public ushort    Count;
    public short     CAddr;
    public ushort    CSW;
    public NineBytes NamePrefix;

    public string GetNamePrefix()
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(NamePrefix);
    }
}

If you run that, it will output:
ABCDEFGHI
BCDEFGHIJ
CDEFGHIJK

Which shows that the data has been correctly cast from the original.
